# How to select some rows as columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello guys? I am working with a MySQL table that stores employees payno, date and meter readings for electricity. I want to select readings for a previous month as previous month reading and current month reading as current month reading, this is what I mean

```
 payno | date       | value 
-------+------------+------------
 6     | 2019-08-31 | 2477
 6     | 2019-09-25 | 2487
 8     | 2019-08-31 | 1651.2
 8     | 2019-09-25 | 1697.6
```

Above is the structure of my table, I want to achieve something like this:

```
 payno | previous month| current month
-------+---------------+------------
 6     | 2477          | 2487
 8     | 1651.2        | 1697.6
```

Notice that the previous month reading are the readings having month(date) as 8 and the current month readings have month(date) as 9.

Comment: which verison of mySQL are you usiing?

Comment: @jimmy8ball I am using MySQL 5.6, does the MYSQL version really matters in this case?

Comment: You could consider a windowed function if you are on a latter version i.e. 8+

Comment: *"I am using MySQL 5.6, does the MYSQL version really matters in this case? "* Yes MySQL version really matters or you can use LEAD/LAG (MySQL 8+) or you simulate that with MySQL's user variables (MySQL 5.1+) or use corelated subqueries or abuse MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT ..

Comment: ... also it is not clear if a `payno` group can have more then two records..

Comment: @BensonKiprono did you have a chance to see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how many readings can be per month, so we'll summarize them.

```
select e.payno,
(   select sum(x1.val) 
    from emp x1 
    where x1.payno=e.payno and month(x1.data)=month(date_sub(e.data, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
    group by x1.payno ) AS prev_month,
(   select sum(x2.val) 
    from emp x2 
    where x2.payno=e.payno and month(x2.data)=month(e.data)
    group by x2.payno ) AS this_month
from emp e
where month(e.data)=9 /* this is where you specify "current" month */
;
```

Comment: I got to look at your answer. I have implemented it. it works fine when both previous month and current month records are available. 
When there are no current month readings, I don't get any results. Is it possible to modify your query such that if there are no records for the current month it gives me previous month readings and the current month readings being either null or 0?

Comment: @BensonKiprono You just asked another question. If you think my code answers your *original* question, then accept the answer,  take my code and ask a new question on SO and somebody will try to answer you.